# curl wierd behaviour when script runs as a cron job

Tags: bash, curl, cron

I have a shell script file which contains a curl command running in a loop. The problem is that when I set the script to run as a cron job, curl doesn't work fine anymore. Most of the times it runs only one time in the loop (first call) which sometimes downloads an incomplete file for that only run!!! I tried to add my working PATH in the script and also in the crontab settings but all to no avail! I'm pasting the problematic part of the code here:

```
for time in 00 03 06 09 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 39 42 45 48 51 54 57 60 63 66 69 72 75 78 81 84 87 90 93 96;
    do
        curl -# -m 300 -C - ftp://ftpserver/filename"$time" --output /home/user/filename"$time"
    done
```

crontab entry:

```
00 11 * * * /home/user/script.sh >> /home/user/log.txt
```

Comment: Please show the crontab entry too. What's the error (output)? You may get this by looking into the users mailbox or redirecting outputs to a logfile by appending `... >/log 2>&1` to the crontab entry. To see the whole script would be helpful too, I think.

Comment: consider  for time in {0..96..3};   - not that it relates to your problem but looks nicer anyway unless your leading zeroes are important in which case  for time in {00..96..3}; do   could do

Comment: @try-catch-finally: I add "2>&1" at the end of the crontab entry, and it works! Would you please tell me what was the problem? I mean how exactly "2>&1" helped to solve the problem.

Comment: Don't you have a typo in your crontab? `/home/user` vs `/home/usr`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: That was a typo in the post only, I corrected it

Comment: Uhm, just realizing it now: do you have to enter a username/password when running it manually? I can't find what `curl` does when omitting username/password. Your question's still lacking the error output. The `-C -` option may cause issues too. Try adding `-v` for more informational output.

Comment: @try-catch-finally: it doesn't generate any error in log file in the form of my crontab command, just skips the curl command. But when I add "2>&1" it works fine! Now that it resolves the issue, I want to know that what does "2>&1" do that makes the curl runs fine!

Comment: It only redirects the text from `stderr` to `stdout` so that the `>` redirection into the logfile will also "catch" the error output too. This probably does not resolve the error, it workarounds it. Either cron stops the execution if something's printed to `stderr` (I never saw this behaviour though) or the rest of your script does something when there's an error.

Comment: @try-catch-finally: Yes I know what "2>&1" does, but I don't know how it relates to solving the issue! My code is so simple though it has about 400 lines, so I don't think that I can post it here.